# Pass function to next function, fire depending on condition. nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

Im using express.js to create a node.js REST server, as a part o this i am also creating a simple session system. I have 3 modules:

- app.js
- highscoreMan.js
- userSession.js

The app.js url for `http://localhost/api/highscores` now calls userSession with given parameters:

```
//Get all highscores
app.get('/api/highscores', function (req, res) {
  userSession.checkValidity(req.query['username'], req.query['sessionid'], highscoreMan.getAll(req, res));
});
```

However, in checkValidity the function that i pass is automatically called:

```
function checkValidity(username, sessionId, callback) {
  userSession.findOne({ userid: username, sessionid: sessionId }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        if(result) {
          callback;
        }
  });
}
```

I only want to run the function being passed given that i get the proper results from the database(other checks will be added later for session dates etc.). How would i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delay calling `highscoreMan.getAll()`, you'll need to make it a statement of another `function` that can be called *later*:

```
app.get('/api/highscores', function (req, res) {
  userSession.checkValidity(req.query['username'], req.query['sessionid'], function () {
    highscoreMan.getAll(req, res);
  });
});
```

Otherwise, it's being called immediately and its `return` value is instead being passed to `userSession.checkValidity()`.

Note that you'll also need to adjust `checkValidity` to call the passed `callback`:

```
// ...
if(result) {
  callback();
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I don't fully understand your problem, couldn't you just do something like this?

```
if (result && some_validator(result)) {
    callback();
}
```